# Consequences of rolling back a migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Newb on my first site, postgres.    I rolled back a migration, and then made another migration.    I left the 2nd migration empty and rails db:migrated.

everything seems normal, but the bad migration is still sitting there, and I don't particularily like it.   I'm just wondering what the consequences are if I carry on.

EDIT:  My question is - if I rollback a migration, when somebody else pulls down, is the migration going to go through naturally and mess up the following migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a new app and you're developing only on your local machine at the moment (and especially if you're developing alone), I would rollback the migrations (as the data in DB, at that point, shouldn't be critical so loss of it shouldn't do any harm and, personally, I prefer not to have needless or even wrong/corrupted migration files at that point in development), remove the corrupted migration file, create the correct migration and run db:migrate and push changes to git.
So (rails 5): 
rails d migration MigrationYouWishToDestroy
rails db:migrate

If you are developing in a team (and the previous migration had already been pushed to repo) and/or are working with data you can't afford to lose via rollbacking, then you should create a new migration that effectively undo's what your previous migration (the one that is bad) did. That way, your co-workers will only need to run db:migrate after pulling changes and that'll be it. Otherwise, they would've had to rollback their db as well and then run db:migrate

Comment: I appreciate that.   So if I roll it back, I can destroy the failed migrations in front that I've just rolled back, and then make new migrations normally.    How do I tell which migration I'm currently at?   ... as in, if I'm rolling back, is there a way to know which was the last migration to be migrated?

Comment: Correct. You can rollback with db:rollback STEP=x where x is the number of migrations you wish to roll back. That way you know how many migrations you're behind and thus know which migration was the last to be migrated.

Comment: I appreciate your help!    I'm attempting to rollback the failed migration, and it's giving me the error I got when attempting to migrate it.   if I db:rollback STEP=2 from this point (jump to the one in front of it), will it skip the failing migration, so then I can then destroy it?

Comment: It won't skip it, no. It runs them in sequence, just like db:migrate. What error are you getting?

Comment: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "band_id" of relation "single_videos" does not exist.      i have a has_one and belongs_to between Band and SingleVideo, and I was trying to make a relation like add_reference :single_videos, :band, index: true

Comment: In that case, I am assuming the migration didn't even go through when you ran db:migrate after you created this migration. So there's no need for running any kind of rollback - or creating a new migration. Just fix the current migration and that should solve your issue ;)

Comment: I apologise and much appreciate the assistance.   In the single video schema I've got t.bigint "bands_id".    I'm pretty sure originally I had add_reference :single_videos, :bands, index: true, but then I tried to add a foreign key, which gave me an error so maybe i rolled it back and put add_reference :single_videos, :band, index: true, but then i'm not sure why there's I've got t.bigint "bands_id".   I apologise for the newbishness, these migrations are somewhat nerve racking

Comment: crisis resolved :)  i appreciate that man.  these migrations freak me out

Comment: No problem. Was just writing a comment of what the code should probably look like, but I'm glad you sorted it out. They're freaky when you begin, yeah, but once you get used to them, they're not so bad ;)